# Java Script Sum Numbers Application do while and for loop

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty understanding a homework assignment. I would appreciate someone helping me with this matter. Please note I am not looking for someone to create the code for me, I am simply trying to understand why my code isn't working. This is the assignment:

> 1. Download the file below.
> 2. In the script element, add a do-while loop that prompts the user for an entry from 1 through 100. If the entry is invalid, display an
>      alert box with this message: “Please enter a number between 1 and
>      100”. Then, continue the loop until the entry is valid.
> 3. After the do-while loop, code a for loop that sums the numbers, and then display the second dialog box above. For instance, the sum for an
>      entry of four 1 + 2 + 3 + 4.
> 4. Add a do-while loop around all of the code that uses the third dialog box above to determine whether the first dialog box should be
>      displayed again so the user can enter another number. The application
>      should end for any entry other than “y”."

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Sum of Numbers</title>
    <script>
        do
        {
            do
            {
                var theNumber = prompt("Enter first number", "10");
                theNumber = parsInt(theNumber);
                var numberOfLoops = (theNumber);
                numberOfLoops = parsInt(numberOfLoops);
                if(isNaN(theNumber) || theNumber <1 || theNumber > 100)
                {
                    alert("Please enter a number between 1 and 100");
                }
            }
            while (isNaN(theNumber) || theNumber <1 || theNumber > 100);

            for (var counter = theNumber; counter>=1; counter--)
            {
                alert(counter);
            }
            sum == (theNumber + counter);
            alert(sum);
            again = prompt("Do it again? ('y' for yes)")
        }
        while(again = 'y');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <!-- Will show after JavaScript has run -->
        <h1>Thanks for using the Sum of Numbers application!</h1>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `sum == (theNumber + counter);` doesn't do an assignment, it does a comparison. You would need to add to `sum` inside the `for` loop, perhaps `sum = sum + counter`, which can be condensed using the `+=` operator as `sum += counter;`.

Comment: `while(again = 'y')` ... this is _assigning_ the value `y` to `again`, when you want to be checking the _equality_, i.e. `while (again === 'y')`

Comment: Add `var sum = 0;` before the `for` loop, and then put the `sum = (theNumber + counter)` inside of the loop. So you have `var sum = 0; for (var counter = theNumber; counter>=1; counter--) { alert(counter); sum = (theNumber + counter); }`

Comment: Okay, thank you guys for this much, the main issue I am having is that when I run the application it asks for the input, then goes directly to the h1 setting completely ignoring everything from the "var numberOfLoops = (theNumber);" onward. Though I did add the changes you suggested.

Comment: There's a typo on `parsInt`. It should be `parseInt`

Comment: Thanks, works perfect now, with all the help above. Especially the typo.